# Remove Server header: AkamaiGHost and Mime-Version

Tags: iis-8, akamai

I have the following setup in web.config file to remove the server headers:

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="Rename server headers" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern="*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="TestServer" />
      </rule>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
```

But on validating with HTTP Verb: TRACE, I am still seeing the Server and Mime-Version headers in the response.

[image]

Can anyone help me here to fix this issue?

Comment: The Server header indicates that you are using Akamai services, https://www.akamai.com/us/en/cdn/ That goes beyond IIS and you shouldn't expect URL Rewrite can help.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li for your quick response. I am reaching out to Akmai team to check anything that they can help to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Akamai can remove the header using a behavior called 'Modify-Outgoing-Response'.